# Firefox inspector goes empty after a couple of requests

Tags: firefox, web-inspector, inspector

I use Firefox inspector a lot, like all day, and now for some reason it works correctly then it goes blank as shown below. I then have to close it and reopen it but it goes blank after about 2 minutes so not a good solution.

Has anyone seen this before, is there a fix?

Firefox 32.0 (just updated, same in 31.0)
Windows 7 Professional 64 bit

[image]

Comment: I'm now up to v33.1.1 and it's still doing it, on every PC I work on too - very frustrating

Comment: I just started getting this with Firefox 81.0. I have to close and re-open my tab to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

This bug in fixed in the latest Firefox.
See:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=945749 and
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1002280

This was triggered by an ID element starting with a number.

**Opening and closing the developer tools resets it for a while.**

Comment: it's not. i have 45.0a2 and just had the same problem (and i have no IDs starting with numbers...)

Comment: Had the same just now ( version 48.0.1 ). No IDs with numbers either. Opening and closing the dev tools helped.